# Possible scope issue with jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, scope

I'm trying to make a jquery plugin (just for fun) and I can't seem to a certain portion to do what I want.

```
(function($){

    var resetText = function(){ if (this.value == "") this.value = this.title; }
    var clearText = function(){ if (this.value == this.title) this.value = ""; }

    $.fn.placeHolder = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            resetText(); // <-- this doesn't work
            $(this).focus(clearText).blur(resetText);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Basically, I want the title attribute to be copied over to the value attribute (if the value is empty) on doc.ready AND on field.blur

As it is now, it works onBlur but not on document.ready

I have a feeling it's a scope thing but honestly I don't know how to fix it.

See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/Usk8h/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `this` issue, not a scope issue.

Do this instead:

```
resetText.call( this );
```

---

The `.call()` method allows you to set the value of `this` in the `resetText()` function to whatever you pass as the first argument.

In this case you're passing the DOM element represented by `this` in the `.each()`.

---

**EDIT:**

You could actually reduce your the plugin down to this:

```
$.fn.placeHolder = function() {
    return this.focus(clearText).blur(resetText).blur(); // <-- triggers blur
};
```

Comment: @Johnny I found this interesting so I read up on it a bit, interesting explanation here:  http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

Comment: @kingjiv - I did the same thing and found a similar article. Thanks for that! I ended up going with the second choice that just triggers the onBlur event but I'm still glad to know that you can override _this_. :)

Answer (score 0):

It does appear to be a scope issue.  How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Usk8h/1/

```
(function($){

    var resetText = function(myThis){ if (myThis.value == "") myThis.value = myThis.title; }
    var clearText = function(myThis){ if (myThis.value == myThis.title) myThis.value = ""; }

    $.fn.placeHolder = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            resetText(this);
            $(this)
                .focus(function(){
                    clearText(this);
                }).blur(function(){
                    resetText(this);   
                });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! Ultimately, I liked the other solution provided better. I just seemed cleaner and more maintainable. Your solution _did_ work though, so thank you for your time.